# Как исключить выполнение функции на страницах AMP в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, amp

Как исключить выполнение функции на страницах AMP в Wordpress?

```
if (!(is_admin() && is_amp_endpoint())) {
    function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
        if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
        if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
        return "$url defer=\"defer\"";
    }
    add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
}
```

Почему этот код срабатывает на AMP страницах? Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Код срабатывает, потому что на страницах is_admin() возвращается false. Исправьте условие в if:

```
if (!(is_admin() || is_amp_endpoint())) {
```

Comment: даже при таком условии функция срабатывает на AMP страницах и они не проходят валидацию. Нельзя использовать атрибут defer в AMP

Comment: Ну как он может срабатывать на amp- страницах? Признак amp-страницы - is_amp_endpoint()  Возвращает true. в этом случае код не сработает. Что у вас выдает `var_dump( is_amp_endpoint() )` ?

Comment: `bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true)` - вот что выдает `var_dump( is_amp_endpoint() );`

Comment: Это все на одной странице?

Comment: да, это выдало на AMP странице

Comment: А где этот код у вас стоит?

Comment: в файле дочерней темы functions.php

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86473/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-spoilt).